# How to disable logging for a particular systemd unit

Tags: linux, logging, systemd

I have a systemd unit, which creates a lot of useless log (around 1GB per day), so I want to disable logging for this unit. How can I manage to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming it's logging by writing to standard out or standard error. In those cases, you can use `StandardOutput=null` or `StandardError=null` to send the output into the void.

See the `systemd.exec(5)` man page for more information on the directives.